# User!Language vs CurrentThread

Tags: c#, reporting-services, culture, rdl

For formatting our Dates in the RDL-Files, we use the following format:

```
=First(FormatDateTime(Fields!SomeDate.Value, 2))
```

According to this [Page](http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs111.htm), it should take the Computer's Regional Settings.

The problem is: If I call the Reporting-Service via another Service and try to set the Language:

```
rs.SetExecutionParameters(MapParameters(Report.Parameters).ToArray(), "de-CH");
```

This gets ignored. I tried to override the Thread-Cultures via

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-CH");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-CH");
```

Which gets ignored as well.
Whats really string: The Reporting-Server itself has de-CH as culture as well, but it keeps using the english date-format.

Can someone tells me what's meant with "Computer's Regional Settings" and why the Reporting-Service refuses to take the passed Culture?

Edit: The language in the Report is

```
=User!Language
```

Generally said I'd like to pass the Report-Language from outside, be it via `CurrentThread` or via Parameter. But both get ignored.

Comment: What is the report Language property value (`Properties`=> `Language`)?

Comment: Also, do you want a fixed culture for `SomeDate` or do you want to configure the culture by execution/report/server?

Comment: I made a Edit to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Instead of [FormatDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a912f2a0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you could use [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and specify your expected output format:

```
=First(Format(Fields!SomeDate.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

Or another alternative to have the culture in a parameter, but in this case you will have to read the long answer.

**Long answer**

Your first attempt with the [SetExecutionParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.setexecutionparameters%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) was to set the culture of the parameters, which does not affect the report itself (only the parameters you pass to it).

Your second attempt was to change the culture of the client application, which also does not affect the report (only the client application culture).

The [FormatDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a912f2a0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function usually uses the computer regional settings, but not in Reporting Services. It will take the report culture, which in your case is `User!Language`.

`User!Language` returns the language configured in the client web browser when browsing to the report server.
I'm not sure what the behavior is when calling from web services (a specific setting taken or default to en-US).

The Report Language property can be an expression, so nothing stops you from adding another text parameter to the report, say, `ReportCulture`, and use this in `Properties` => `Language`:

```
=Parameters!ReportCulture.Value
```

You would have to keep using your expression for the dates:

```
=First(FormatDateTime(Fields!SomeDate.Value, 2))
```

You can configure a default value (`de-CH` in your case), so that this setting will only be specified if you want to override it.

Comment: Thanks alot, sadly the most interesting parth would be "I'm not sure what the behavior is when calling from web services (a specific setting taken or default to en-US).", but I get the idea how it works.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller - Yes, unfortunately I haven't found any official information on this... If you really want to know if it is possible to do it from the webservice, you could still post the question on the MSDN forums, where you will have more chance to have an answer from MSFT.